# How to avoid x axis changed when add marks?

Tags: wpf, teechart

I have a problem to consult,when I use the Line of the Point style and show the marks, the x axis would have a problem.When annotate the code (lineSeries5.Add(5, 1,"ghgh");),the x axis shows normally like number 1,2.....,but when I use this code (lineSeries5.Add(5, 1,"ghgh"); ), the x axis becomes 'ghgh'，I wonder if how to solve this problem. My purpose is showing the contents which I want to shows in the marks,but the x axis should not be changed. Waiting for your help, thank you very much!

```
private Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Points lineSeries5;

this.lineSeries5 = new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Points();

this.tChart1.Series.Add(this.lineSeries5);

lineSeries5.Marks.Visible = true;
lineSeries5.Marks.Transparent = true;            


lineSeries5.Pointer.Style = Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.PointerStyles.Nothing;
**lineSeries5.Add(5, 1,"ghgh");**
lineSeries5.Add(9, 3);
```

Comment: Didn't work with Steema before, but they are usually the same ...can you post some visual aid to show what you want? Also, any specific reason you chose Steema? can you / would you consider alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you want in your axis labels are values instead of labelsText, you must change the Axis labels style as I do in next line:

```
   tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = AxisLabelStyle.Value;
```

Could you tell us if previous code solve your problem?

Thanks,